# Redirect all .html to WordPress url except some with .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have Rewrite rule to redirect all pages that ends with .html and it's working fine until I realized that there are folder pages that I don't need to redirect to WP/php urls.

Can I do an exception to my .htaccess? here's my current .htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.+)\.html?$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have a folder that I still want .html to work.

- www.example.com/htmls/index.html
- www.example.com/htmls/about.html

I don't want all files in the folder /htmls/ for .html to be removed.
How can I edit my .htaccess to do just that?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RewriteCond` to skip a certain folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/htmls/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)\.html?$ /$1/ [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```